# PHP switch cases title

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how to do this part. I was wondering, how can i set titles for each case?

As an example, if i have my title tag as `<title>$page_title</title>` , can i turn that variable into a string for each cases or how does that work?

I have tried doing it by adding `$page_title = "some title"` in each case but i assume that the variable must be put before the actual `<title>$page_title</title>`

I included a file above the header `include = 'inc/titles.php';` and tried to set each variable from there but that does only change the title for each file, not case.

EDIT: added a better example

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $page_title;?></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['page')){
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    switch($page){
      case '1':
          $page_title = "case 1";
      break;

      case '2':
         $page_title = "case 2";
      break;
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show your code, it's hard to understand what you are actually asking

Comment: You are outputting before setting the variable. Move the assignment before the `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

try the php before the html title

```
<html>
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['page')){
        $page = $_GET['page'];
        switch($page){
          case '1':
              $page_title = "case 1";
          break;

          case '2':
             $page_title = "case 2";
          break;
        }
    }
    ?>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $page_title;?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: can i use the same cases twice? Because my cases has a lot of content in them and i doubt i can put them outside of the body.

Comment: it doesn't matter, you can put them outside of the body